# Get file modification time in a specific format (yyyymmddhh24miss)

Tags: linux, date, stat

I want to get the modification time of a file in a specific format.
How can I do that ?
I know about

```
stat -c %x find.txt
```

but I need this format:

```
yyyymmddhh24miss
```

I'm using `ksh` on `Linux 2.6.18-406.el5 x86_64` if it matters.

Comment: unix and /bin/ksh

Comment: Linux 2.6.18-406.el5 x86_64 and /bin/ksh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
/bin/date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S -d "$(/usr/bin/stat -c %x find.txt)"
```

Answer (score 5):

With GNU tools:

```
find file -prune -printf '%TY%Tm%Td%TH%TM%TS\n'
```

Or

```
date -r file +%Y%m%d%H%M%S.%N
```

(though beware that for symlinks, that displays the modification time of the *target* of the symlink, not the symlink itself (which may be just as well as who cares about the mtime of a symlink, see `-L` with `find` to do the same)).

If your `ksh` is `ksh93` and it has been built with the `date` builtin enabled:

```
command /opt/ast/bin/date -m -f %Y%m%d%H%M%S.%N file
```

(`command /opt/ast/bin/date` invokes the `date` builtin bound to `/opt/ast/bin/date`, if you add `/opt/ast/bin` at the front of `$PATH`, those builtins will be invoked automatically when you call them by name).

If you don't care for the fractional part, remove the `.%N` or for `find`, replace `%TS` with `%.2TS`.

Note that the time will be given in the current timezone. As this date format doesn't include the UTC offset, it can be ambiguous. For instance in my mainland British timezone:

```
$ date -r file1
Sun 30 Oct 01:00:00 BST 2016
$ date -r file2
Sun 30 Oct 01:00:00 GMT 2016
```

Those two files have a modification time that are 3600 seconds apart, one before, one after the change to winter time but still at the same wall clock time (as that clock has been moved back one hour in the interval).

```
$ find file? -prune -printf '%TY%Tm%Td%TH%TM%TS\n'
20161030010000.0000000000
20161030010000.0000000000
```

To have unambiguous times, you can include the UTC offset:

```
$ find file? -prune -printf '%TY%Tm%Td%TH%TM%TS%Tz\n'
20161030010000.0000000000+0100
20161030010000.0000000000+0000
```

Or give the time in UTC:

```
$ TZ=UTC0 find file? -prune -printf '%TY%Tm%Td%TH%TM%TS\n'
20161030000000.0000000000
20161030010000.0000000000
```

Comment: Unless `file` is a directory, `-prune` has no effect.

Comment: Yes, which is why it's safe to use on any kind of file, and you want to use it in case the file might be of type _directory_.

Comment: You could as well include a `zsh/zstat` solution for completeness...

Answer (score 1):

The file *modification* time, could be formatted with date:

```
$ date -d @"$(stat -c %Y file1)" +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S'
```

Use `%X` for last access time and `%Z` for last change.

However, the maximum resolution of `%X`, `%Y` and `%Z` is seconds.
For nanoseconds resolution use the `%x`, `%y` and `%z` options:

```
$ date -d "$(stat -c %y file1)" +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S.%N'
20151101020000.012345678
```

As we are using date already, we can simplify by using date's `-r` option, or we can use find's formatted output:

```
$ date -r file1 +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S%z'
20151101010000-0500
$ find file1 -printf '%TY%Tm%Td%TH%TM%2.2TS%Tz\n'
20151101010000-0500
```

The resolution of the above commands is seconds. If nanoseconds are needed:

```
$ date -r file1 +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S.%N%z'
20151101010000.012345678-0500
$ find file1 -printf '%TY%Tm%Td%TH%TM%TS%Tz\n'
20151101010000.0123456780-0500
```

Those two commands give modification time
In date there is no way to get access or status time with the `-r` option.
In find: Change %T to %A for access time and to %C for status change time

---

## About Time Zone

Please note that all the above commands are affected by the time zone used:

```
$ date -r file1 +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S.%N%z'
20151101010000.012345678
$ TZ=GMT0 date -r file1 +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S.%N%z'
20151101060000.012345678
```

Note the Hour change from `01` to `06`. That happens because the computer used had a time zone set for `America/New_York`. When the time is calculated at the `GMT0` offset (aka `GMT` or `GMT+0` or `GMT-0`) its value increase in 5 hours.

Also, the use of local time values (if incomplete) may present equal values when they are actually different:

```
$ date -r file1 +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S.%N'; date -r file2 +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S.%N'
20151101010000.012345678
20151101010000.012345678
```

That's why the tailing `%z` is needed for **local** times:

```
$ date -r file1 +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S.%N%z'; date -r file2 +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S.%N%z'
20151101010000.012345678-0500
20151101010000.012345678-0400
```

That makes the values different. But this kind of format makes sorting by time difficult. That is why the best solution is to use `GMT` times because the time offset (`%z`) is always `0` and can be omitted:

```
$ ( TZ=GMT0; date -r file1 +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S.%N'; date -r file2 +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S.%N')
20151101060000.012345678
20151101050000.012345678
```

And sorting is possible.

<sup>[1]</sup> Values used to touch files used.
touch -m -d '20151101 01:00:00.012345678-05' file1
touch -a -d '20151101 01:00:00.987654321-05' file1
touch -m -d '20151101 01:00:00.012345678-04' file2
touch -a -d '20151101 01:00:00.987654321-04' file2